# How to highlight new line (LF) symbol in VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In Microsoft Word, there is a feature that allows you to show the special symbol for line break (e.g, pilcrows – `¶`).

How I can achieve a similar result in VSC? The symbol does not have to be identical.

May be there is some extension. I did research but did not find any setting referring to it.

Also may be there is a some setting to show LF, because for space character VSC has dot (`•`) symbol.

Comment: you can write an extension that adds a decorator for pilcrow `before` the newline character

Comment: @rioV8 thx for the comment. Actually I don't need the same exact symbol as in Word. It would be better to find the already written extension instead of writing my own..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists an extension that should satisfy your needs called [Render Line Endings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=medo64.render-crlf).

You can customize the symbol shown for all three CRLF, CR, and LF.

[image: render line endings character settings]

In my screenshot I set line feed to be `¶` (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + 20 on keyboard).  Alternatively the JSON for this in the settings JSON is:

```json
{
   "code-eol.newlineCharacter": "¶"
}
```

Then in an editor, when I have my ending line sequence set to LF, it shows the `¶` character:

[image: example text with ¶ character]